# How to consume a SOAP web service with SSL in Java?

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, soap

I have a Java application that connects to a series of SOAP Web Services. These Web Services use HTTP and work just fine but we need them to work with SSL.

This is an example web service. All of the other ones look the same.

```
public Usuario LoginUsuario(String user, String password, int perfil){
     SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory;
    try {
        soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();

        SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

        // Sends SOAP message to SOAP server
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.load(new FileInputStream("ws.properties"));

        String url = props.getProperty("ws");
        SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequestLogin(user, password, perfil), url);

        // Gets SOAP response and then processes it
        Usuario usu = getSOAPResponseLogin(soapResponse);

        return usu;
    }
    catch (SOAPException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(UsuarioDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (UnsupportedOperationException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(UsuarioDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(UsuarioDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(UsuarioDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

I know that I have to install a certificate in my JVM if I'm not mistaken but still I'm not sure.

EDIT: So should I have to modify anything on the code above if I want to connect to a SSL web service? And if so how?

Thanks in advance

Comment: its not clear what is the question?

Comment: If the server Cerys are signed by a proper ca you should not need to install the cert locally

Comment: Peter : Ok but should I change any part of the code to connect to the web service?

Comment: Sergey: Should I have to modify anything if I want to connect to a SSL web service?